# null pointer exception on out.println("username,," + username);

Tags: java, android

my code for a simple chat with java. I'm getting a null pointer exception in while sending the username on line  `out.println("username,," + username);` and I don't know why

```
package guc.protocols.checkers;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
//import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener,
        Runnable {

    static Socket socket;
    static BufferedReader in;
    static PrintWriter out;
    Activity act = this;
    String inputMessage;

    EditText edit_username;
    Button btn_connect;
    String username;

    boolean exitFromLoop = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        edit_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_username);
        btn_connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_connect);

        btn_connect.setOnClickListener(this);
        try {
            Thread thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == btn_connect) {
            username = edit_username.getText().toString();
            if (username.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "You must enter your username", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                return;
            }

            out.println("username,," + username);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 5454);
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
            out.println("Hello");

            while (!exitFromLoop) {
                inputMessage = in.readLine();
                if (inputMessage != null) {
                    Log.i("input", inputMessage);
                    if (inputMessage.equals("This is the server")) {
                        // everything is ok - do nothing
                    } else if (inputMessage.startsWith("username,,")) {

                        String response = inputMessage.split(",,")[1];
                        Log.i("input", response);
                        if (response.equals("yes")) {
                            exitFromLoop = true;
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Username Available",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                                            getApplicationContext(),
                                            ConnectedUsersActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });

                        } else {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Username Already Taken !!",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void sendToServer(String message) {
        out.println(message);
    }

    public static String receiveFromServer() {

        String received = "";
        try {
            received = in.readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return received;
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't assigned a value to `out`.

Comment: out isn't defined, so it defaults to null. It won't be set until the thread actually runs and the creation of the Socket completes, which could be seconds to minutes (if the CPU is pegged or the remote computer is slow to respond/does not exist). You ought to create out on the UI thread before starting the thread.

Comment: can you tell me how can i do that on my code